# Differences in pyside6 and pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, pyside6

I am writing a program in Pyside6 and use my own Titlebar.
When running with pyside6, I get this problem.
[image: Pyside example]
I need to remove this space

Using PyQt5 everything is fine

[image: Pyqt example]

What differences in the work of these frameworks can cause this problem and what should be used to fix it.
the code on both frameworks is the same, but the result is different, I can't understand why this is happening

My code using PySide6

**TextEditorQt.py**

```
from PySide6 import QtGui
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from TextEditorUI import Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow  # импорт нашего сгенерированного файла
from PySide6.QtCore import QSettings, QPoint, QSize
from Titlebar import FramelessWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(762, 580)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.open_action = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.open_action.setObjectName(u"open_action")
        self.newfile_action = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.newfile_action.setObjectName(u"newfile_action")
        self.save_action = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.save_action.setObjectName(u"save_action")
        self.saveas_action = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.saveas_action.setObjectName(u"saveas_action")
        self.exit_action = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.exit_action.setObjectName(u"exit_action")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(u"textEdit")
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet(u"alternate-background-color: rgb(85, 0, 255);\n"
                                    "background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 762, 22))
        self.menu = QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName(u"menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())
        self.menu.addAction(self.open_action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.newfile_action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.save_action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.saveas_action)
        self.menu.addSeparator()
        self.menu.addAction(self.exit_action)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Matewriter", None))
        self.open_action.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041e\u0442\u043a\u0440\u044b\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.newfile_action.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041d\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0439", None))
        self.save_action.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0421\u043e\u0445\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.saveas_action.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow",
                                                              u"\u0421\u043e\u0445\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c \u043a\u0430\u043a...",
                                                              None))
        self.exit_action.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0412\u044b\u0445\u043e\u0434", None))
        # if QT_CONFIG(tooltip)
        self.textEdit.setToolTip(
            QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>", None))
        # endif // QT_CONFIG(tooltip)
        self.menu.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0424\u0430\u0439\u043b", None))
    # retranslateUi


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.ico'))

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.curFile = ''
        self.setCurrentFile('')
        self.createStatusBar()

        self.textEdit.document().contentsChanged.connect(self.documentWasModified)

        self.setCurrentFile('')
        self.settings = QSettings('Matewriter', 'Matewriter')
        self.exit_action.triggered.connect(QApplication.quit)
        self.save_action.triggered.connect(self.save)
        self.open_action.triggered.connect(self.open)
        self.newfile_action.triggered.connect(self.newFile)
        self.saveas_action.triggered.connect(self.saveAs)
        self.open_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        self.newfile_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
        self.save_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')
        # Конфиги окна
        windowScreenGeometry = self.settings.value("windowScreenGeometry")
        windowScreenState = self.settings.value("windowScreenState")
        if windowScreenGeometry:
            self.restoreGeometry(windowScreenGeometry)

        else:
            #            self.resize(600)
            self.resize(600, 600)  # !!!

        if windowScreenState:
            self.restoreState(windowScreenState)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.settings.setValue("windowScreenGeometry", self.saveGeometry())
        self.settings.setValue("windowScreenState", self.saveState())
        if self.maybeSave():
            self.writeSettings()
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def newFile(self):
        if self.maybeSave():
            self.textEdit.clear()
            self.setCurrentFile('')

    def open(self):
        if self.maybeSave():
            fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)
            if fileName:
                self.loadFile(fileName)

    def save(self):
        if self.curFile:
            return self.saveFile(self.curFile)

        return self.saveAs()

    def saveAs(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self)
        if fileName:
            return self.saveFile(fileName)

        return False

    def documentWasModified(self):
        self.setWindowModified(self.textEdit.document().isModified())

    def createStatusBar(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Ready")

    def readSettings(self):
        settings = QSettings("MateWriter")
        pos = settings.value("pos", QPoint(200, 200))
        size = settings.value("size", QSize(400, 400))
        self.resize(size)
        self.move(pos)

    def writeSettings(self):
        settings = QSettings("MateWriter")
        settings.setValue("pos", self.pos())
        settings.setValue("size", self.size())

    def maybeSave(self):
        if self.textEdit.document().isModified():
            ret = QMessageBox.warning(self, "MateWriter",
                                      "The document has been modified.\nDo you want to save "
                                      "your changes?",
                                      QMessageBox.Save | QMessageBox.Discard | QMessageBox.Cancel)

            if ret == QMessageBox.Save:
                return self.save()

            if ret == QMessageBox.Cancel:
                return False

        return True

    def loadFile(self, fileName):
        file = QFile(fileName)
        if not file.open(QFile.ReadOnly | QFile.Text):
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "MateWriter",
                                "Cannot read file %s:\n%s." % (fileName, file.errorString()))
            return

        inf = QTextStream(file)
        QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.WaitCursor)
        self.textEdit.setPlainText(inf.readAll())
        QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()

        self.setCurrentFile(fileName)
        self.statusBar().showMessage("File loaded", 2000)

    def saveFile(self, fileName):
        file = QFile(fileName)
        if not file.open(QFile.WriteOnly | QFile.Text):
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "MateWriter",
                                "Cannot write file %s:\n%s." % (fileName, file.errorString()))
            return False

        outf = QTextStream(file)
        QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.WaitCursor)
        outf << self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()

        self.setCurrentFile(fileName)
        self.statusBar().showMessage("File saved", 2000)
        return True

    def setCurrentFile(self, fileName):
        self.curFile = fileName
        self.textEdit.document().setModified(False)
        self.setWindowModified(False)

        if self.curFile:
            shownName = self.strippedName(self.curFile)
        else:
            shownName = 'untitled.txt'

        self.setWindowTitle(" %s[*] - MateWriter" % shownName)

    def strippedName(self, fullFileName):
        return QFileInfo(fullFileName).fileName()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    w = FramelessWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle('Тестовая строка заголовка')
    w.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Qt.ico'))

    #    w.setWidget(MainWindow(MainWindow))       # Добавить свое окно
    w.setWidget(MainWindow())  # !!!

    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Titlebar.py**

```
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, Signal, QPoint, QFileInfo
from PySide6.QtGui import QFont, QEnterEvent, QPainter, QColor, QPen
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel,
                             QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy, QPushButton)



class TitleBar(QWidget):

    # Сигнал минимизации окна
    windowMinimumed = Signal()
    # увеличить максимальный сигнал окна
    windowMaximumed = Signal()
    # сигнал восстановления окна
    windowNormaled = Signal()
    # сигнал закрытия окна
    windowClosed = Signal()
    # Окно мобильных
    windowMoved = Signal(QPoint)
    # Сигнал Своя Кнопка +++
    signalButtonMy = Signal()


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TitleBar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


        # Поддержка настройки фона qss
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        self.mPos     = None
        self.iconSize = 20                     # Размер значка по умолчанию

        # Установите цвет фона по умолчанию, иначе он будет прозрачным из-за влияния родительского окна
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(palette.Window, QColor(240, 240, 240))
        self.setPalette(palette)

        # макет
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self, spacing=0)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # значок окна
        self.iconLabel = QLabel(self)

        self.iconLabel.setMargin(10)
#       self.iconLabel.setScaledContents(True)
        layout.addWidget(self.iconLabel)


        # название окна
        self.titleLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.titleLabel.setMargin(2)
        layout.addWidget(self.titleLabel)

        # Средний телескопический бар
        layout.addSpacerItem(QSpacerItem(
            40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum))

        # Использовать шрифты Webdings для отображения значков
        font = self.font() or QFont()
        font.setFamily('Webdings')


        # Своя Кнопка ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        self.buttonMy = QPushButton(
            '@', self, clicked=self.showButtonMy, font=font, objectName='buttonMy')
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonMy)


        # Свернуть кнопку
        self.buttonMinimum = QPushButton(
            '0', self, clicked=self.windowMinimumed.emit, font=font, objectName='buttonMinimum')
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonMinimum)

        # Кнопка Max / restore
        self.buttonMaximum = QPushButton(
            '1', self, clicked=self.showMaximized, font=font, objectName='buttonMaximum')
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonMaximum)

        # Кнопка закрытия
        self.buttonClose = QPushButton(
            'r', self, clicked=self.windowClosed.emit, font=font, objectName='buttonClose')
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonClose)

        # начальная высота
        self.setHeight()

    # +++ Вызывается по нажатию кнопки buttonMy
    def showButtonMy(self):
        print("Своя Кнопка ")
        self.signalButtonMy.emit()

    def showMaximized(self):
        if self.buttonMaximum.text() == '1':
            # Максимизировать
            self.buttonMaximum.setText('2')
            self.windowMaximumed.emit()
        else:  # Восстановить
            self.buttonMaximum.setText('1')
            self.windowNormaled.emit()

    def setHeight(self, height=38):
        """ Установка высоты строки заголовка """
        self.setMinimumHeight(height)
        self.setMaximumHeight(height)
        # Задайте размер правой кнопки  ?
        self.buttonMinimum.setMinimumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonMinimum.setMaximumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonMaximum.setMinimumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonMaximum.setMaximumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonClose.setMinimumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonClose.setMaximumSize(height, height)

        self.buttonMy.setMinimumSize(height, height)
        self.buttonMy.setMaximumSize(height, height)

    def setTitle(self, title):
        """ Установить заголовок """
        self.titleLabel.setText(title)

    def setIcon(self, icon):
        """ настройки значокa """
        self.iconLabel.setPixmap(icon.pixmap(self.iconSize, self.iconSize))

    def setIconSize(self, size):
        """ Установить размер значка """
        self.iconSize = size

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        super(TitleBar, self).enterEvent(event)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        super(TitleBar, self).mouseDoubleClickEvent(event)
        self.showMaximized()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """ Событие клика мыши """
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.mPos = event.pos()
        event.accept()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        ''' Событие отказов мыши '''
        self.mPos = None
        event.accept()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton and self.mPos:
            self.windowMoved.emit(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos() - self.mPos))
        event.accept()


# Перечислить верхнюю левую, нижнюю правую и четыре неподвижные точки
Left, Top, Right, Bottom, LeftTop, RightTop, LeftBottom, RightBottom = range(8)


class FramelessWindow(QWidget):

    # Четыре периметра
    Margins = 5

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FramelessWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._pressed  = False
        self.Direction = None
        self.resize(762, 580)

        # Фон прозрачный
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)

        # Нет границы
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        # Отслеживание мыши
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

        # макет
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self, spacing=0)
        # Зарезервировать границы для изменения размера окна без полей
        layout.setContentsMargins(
            self.Margins, self.Margins, self.Margins, self.Margins)
        # Панель заголовка
        self.titleBar = TitleBar(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.titleBar)

        # слот сигнала
        self.titleBar.windowMinimumed.connect(self.showMinimized)
        self.titleBar.windowMaximumed.connect(self.showMaximized)
        self.titleBar.windowNormaled.connect(self.showNormal)
        self.titleBar.windowClosed.connect(self.close)
        self.titleBar.windowMoved.connect(self.move)
        self.windowTitleChanged.connect(self.titleBar.setTitle)
        self.windowIconChanged.connect(self.titleBar.setIcon)

    def setTitleBarHeight(self, height=38):
        """ Установка высоты строки заголовка """
        self.titleBar.setHeight(height)

    def setIconSize(self, size):
        """ Установка размера значка """
        self.titleBar.setIconSize(size)

    def setWidget(self, widget):
        """ Настройте свои собственные элементы управления """
        if hasattr(self, '_widget'):
            return
        self._widget = widget
        # Установите цвет фона по умолчанию, иначе он будет прозрачным из-за влияния родительского окна
        self._widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        palette = self._widget.palette()
        palette.setColor(palette.Window, QColor(240, 240, 240))
        self._widget.setPalette(palette)
        self._widget.installEventFilter(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(self._widget)

    def move(self, pos):
        if self.windowState() == Qt.WindowMaximized or self.windowState() == Qt.WindowFullScreen:
            # Максимизировать или полноэкранный режим не допускается
            return
        super(FramelessWindow, self).move(pos)

    def showMaximized(self):
        """ Чтобы максимизировать, удалите верхнюю, нижнюю, левую и правую границы.
            Если вы не удалите его, в пограничной области будут пробелы. """
        super(FramelessWindow, self).showMaximized()
        self.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

    def showNormal(self):
        """ Восстановить, сохранить верхнюю и нижнюю левую и правую границы,
            иначе нет границы, которую нельзя отрегулировать """
        super(FramelessWindow, self).showNormal()
        self.layout().setContentsMargins(
            self.Margins, self.Margins, self.Margins, self.Margins)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        """ Фильтр событий, используемый для решения мыши в других элементах
            управления и восстановления стандартного стиля мыши """
        if isinstance(event, QEnterEvent):
            self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        return super(FramelessWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        """ Поскольку это полностью прозрачное фоновое окно, жесткая для поиска
            граница с прозрачностью 1 рисуется в событии перерисовывания, чтобы отрегулировать размер окна. """
        super(FramelessWindow, self).paintEvent(event)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(255, 255, 255, 1), 2 * self.Margins))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """ Событие клика мыши """
        super(FramelessWindow, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self._mpos = event.pos()
            self._pressed = True

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        ''' Событие отказов мыши '''
        super(FramelessWindow, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self._pressed = False
        self.Direction = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        """ Событие перемещения мыши """
        super(FramelessWindow, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        pos = event.pos()
        xPos, yPos = pos.x(), pos.y()
        wm, hm = self.width() - self.Margins, self.height() - self.Margins
        if self.isMaximized() or self.isFullScreen():
            self.Direction = None
            self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
            return
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton and self._pressed:
            self._resizeWidget(pos)
            return
        if xPos <= self.Margins and yPos <= self.Margins:
            # Верхний левый угол
            self.Direction = LeftTop
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)
        elif wm <= xPos <= self.width() and hm <= yPos <= self.height():
            # Нижний правый угол
            self.Direction = RightBottom
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)
        elif wm <= xPos and yPos <= self.Margins:
            # верхний правый угол
            self.Direction = RightTop
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeBDiagCursor)
        elif xPos <= self.Margins and hm <= yPos:
            # Нижний левый угол
            self.Direction = LeftBottom
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeBDiagCursor)
        elif 0 <= xPos <= self.Margins and self.Margins <= yPos <= hm:
            # Влево
            self.Direction = Left
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeHorCursor)
        elif wm <= xPos <= self.width() and self.Margins <= yPos <= hm:
            # Право
            self.Direction = Right
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeHorCursor)
        elif self.Margins <= xPos <= wm and 0 <= yPos <= self.Margins:
            # выше
            self.Direction = Top
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeVerCursor)
        elif self.Margins <= xPos <= wm and hm <= yPos <= self.height():
            # ниже
            self.Direction = Bottom
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeVerCursor)

    def _resizeWidget(self, pos):
        """ Отрегулируйте размер окна """
        if self.Direction == None:
            return
        mpos = pos - self._mpos
        xPos, yPos = mpos.x(), mpos.y()
        geometry = self.geometry()
        x, y, w, h = geometry.x(), geometry.y(), geometry.width(), geometry.height()
        if self.Direction == LeftTop:          # Верхний левый угол
            if w - xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                x += xPos
                w -= xPos
            if h - yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                y += yPos
                h -= yPos
        elif self.Direction == RightBottom:    # Нижний правый угол
            if w + xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                w += xPos
                self._mpos = pos
            if h + yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                h += yPos
                self._mpos = pos
        elif self.Direction == RightTop:       # верхний правый угол
            if h - yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                y += yPos
                h -= yPos
            if w + xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                w += xPos
                self._mpos.setX(pos.x())
        elif self.Direction == LeftBottom:     # Нижний левый угол
            if w - xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                x += xPos
                w -= xPos
            if h + yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                h += yPos
                self._mpos.setY(pos.y())
        elif self.Direction == Left:            # Влево
            if w - xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                x += xPos
                w -= xPos
            else:
                return
        elif self.Direction == Right:           # Право
            if w + xPos > self.minimumWidth():
                w += xPos
                self._mpos = pos
            else:
                return
        elif self.Direction == Top:             # выше
            if h - yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                y += yPos
                h -= yPos
            else:
                return
        elif self.Direction == Bottom:          # ниже
            if h + yPos > self.minimumHeight():
                h += yPos
                self._mpos = pos
            else:
                return
        self.setGeometry(x, y, w, h)
```

Comment: Please do not create [duplicated questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67051263/different-result-using-pyqt5-and-pyside6). If your original question doesn't get answered it probably means that nobody has been able to find an answer yet. Also, consider that while they have been officially released, both Qt6 and PyQt6 are still in early stage, some modules or classes have been temporarily removed, disabled or lack some features. If you feel like yours is a bug (it could surely be!), try to reduce your code and submit a report on the [official tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the named arguments to QVBoxLayout are not supported

```
layout = QVBoxLayout(self, spacing=0)
```

The property needs to be set by calling the setter.

```
layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
```